# Convert deprecated HttpParams

Tags: android, android-studio, deprecated

I can not find a post that will convert the HttpParams or HttpConnectionParams to a usable non-deprecated script.

```
@Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
        values.put("name", user.name);
        values.put("age", user.age + "");
        values.put("username", user.username);
        values.put("password", user.password);

        HttpParams httpRequestParams = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpRequestParams, CONNECTION_Timeout);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpRequestParams, CONNECTION_Timeout);

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpRequestParams);
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(SERVER_ADDRESS + "Register.php");

        try {
            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(dataToSend));
            client.execute(post);
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution that I have applied to the problem that httpclient deprecated in this version of android 22`

```
public static final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0";



public static String sendPost(String _url,Map<String,String> parameter)  {
    StringBuilder params=new StringBuilder("");
    String result="";
    try {
    for(String s:parameter.keySet()){
        params.append("&"+s+"=");

            params.append(URLEncoder.encode(parameter.get(s),"UTF-8"));
    }


    String url =_url;
    URL obj = new URL(_url);
    HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
    con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "UTF-8");

    con.setDoOutput(true);
    OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(con.getOutputStream());
    outputStreamWriter.write(params.toString());
    outputStreamWriter.flush();

    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
    System.out.println("Post parameters : " + params);
    System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine + "\n");
    }
    in.close();

        result = response.toString();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
    return  result;
    }

}
```

Comment: Sorry I am a bit of a beginner. Is there any chance you could be more specific to my situation?

Answer (score 0):

Http client for Android is now fully depricated. Now you should use OkHttp client by Square.
http://square.github.io/okhttp/
It is easier and more handy to use. Thet was the reason it is now supporting as default http client by Google.